# multiprocessing speed difference

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am doing some sort of pattern matching on a dataset (English sentences) of 40 MB. To improve the speed I used **multiprocessing**. I created a **Pool** of *4* processes. Initially I kept the content of the file in a *variable*, then split it to 4 equal parts and sent it to the function.
This is how I am doing:

```
nl_split =  content.split('\n') #The whole data kept in content
lenNl=int(len(nl_split)/4)
part1,part2,part3,part4 = '\n'.join(nl_split[0:lenNl]),'\n'.join(nl_split[lenNl+1:2*lenNl]),'\n'.join(nl_split[2*lenNl+1:3*lenNl]),'\n'.join(nl_split[3*lenNl+1:4*lenNl])
pr = Pool(4)
rValue=pr.map(match_some_pattern,[part1,part2,part3,part4])
```

Taking `90.148968935` Sec.

As a **second approach**, I divided the file into 4 and passed to the function as seperate files.

```
pr = Pool(4)
rValue=pr.map(match_some_pattern,['part1.txt','part2.txt','part3.txt','part4.txt'])
```

Taking `48.5109400749` Sec.

When I compare their speed of execution, I found that the **second approach is far better than the first one**. I was thinking that the first approach should be better than the second one, since less file operations are there. But the result was opposite!

Why second approach is consuming less time than the first one ?

Comment: Please show the code that is `#content divided into 4`. If you'd like assistance, it's good to include a [mcve]

Comment: Also, can you provide actual values of how long it took? The difference between 4 seconds and 40 seconds is more significant than 4 ms and 400 ms.

Comment: Your operating system is relevant too

Comment: In the first approach that data in each part is pickled before being sent and unpickled in the receiving process. In the second, this only happens to the filenames.

Comment: @cricket_007 Edited the code part

Comment: I got it. I am doing some sort of preprocessing of the input file. While splitting it to multiple files, I did it parallelly for each file (I wrote that code inside the function `match_some_pattern`).  When keeping it in a variable and split to 4 variables, I am doing the preprocessing at once ( Not inside the function `match_some_pattern` ). That made the first approach heavy.